# SQL Server schema for messaging system

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am creating a few tables for a messaging system so I have:

```
create table Users 
(
    Id int identity not null
       constraint PK_User_Id primary key clustered (Id),
    Name nvarchar (400) not null
)

create table Messages 
(
    Id int identity not null
       constraint PK_Message_Id primary key clustered (Id),
    AuthorId int not null,
    Subject nvarchar (400) not null,
    Content nvarchar (max) not null
)

create table Recipients 
(
    Id int identity not null
       constraint PK_Recipient_Id primary key clustered (Id),
    RecipientId int not null
)

alter table Messages
add constraint FK_AuthorId foreign key (AuthorId) references Users(Id);

alter table Recipients
add constraint FK_RecipientId foreign key (RecipientId) references Users(Id);
```

I am not sure if this is the best option ...

How to include groups of users and send a message to a group?

Comment: To connect many users to a single email you need to create a table `EmailRecipients` with PK = `MessageID`, `RecipientID`. If Message ID 83 has 3 recipients you write those recipients to this table with MessageID=83. Your Recipients table appears to have a redundant column `id`. Perhaps this is what your intention was there.

Answer (score 0):

To have a group email design, you can have a Group table and a GroupUser table:

```
Create table Group
(
GroupID int identity(1,1) primary key,
GroupName varchar(50) not null
)
go

Create table GroupUser
(
GroupUserID int identity(1,1) primary key,
GroupID int not null,
UserID int not null,
Constraint FK_GroupUser_Group foreign key(GroupID) references Group(GroupID),
Constrannt FK_GroupUser_UserID foreign key(UserID) references Users(ID)
)
go
```